# How to get Facebook page shared posts rather than feeds for Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

```
.controller('FeedCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, OpenFB, $ionicLoading, $ionicScrollDelegate) {

            $scope.show = function () {
                $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
                    content: 'Loading feed...'
                });
            };
            $scope.hide = function () {
                $ionicLoading.loading.hide();
            };
            function loadFeed()
            {
                $scope.show();
                OpenFB.get('/107621857718/feed', {limit: 5})
                        .success(function (result) {
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            $scope.loaded = result.data;
                            // Used with pull-to-refresh
                            //$scope.loaded = [];
                            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
                        })
                        .error(function (data) {
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            alert(data.error.message);
                        });


            }
            ;
            $scope.checkScroll = function () {

                var currentTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('libScroll').getScrollPosition().top;
                var maxTop = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('libScroll').getScrollView().__maxScrollTop;

                if ((currentTop >= maxTop) && (!$scope.libraryLoading))
                {
                    loadMore();
                }
            };
            function loadMore()
            {

                $scope.show();
                OpenFB.get('/107621857718/feed')
                        .success(function (result) {

                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            $scope.loaded = result.data;
                            // Used with pull-to-refresh

                            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

                        })

                        .error(function (data) {
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                            alert(data.error.message);
                        });
            }

            $scope.doRefresh = loadFeed;
            loadFeed();



        });
```

For above part I am getting posts which is given by other users to page but I want posts shared by page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `/{page_id}/posts` if you only want the Page's posts.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

> /{page-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this page.

As the last post is from 2012, apparantly the `since` parameter has to be added to receive results:

```
/107621857718/posts?since=1325376000
```

will get all the posts from January 1st 2012 on.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=107621857718%2Fposts%3Fsince%3D1325376000&

Comment: not working. I got blank result.=>   {
   "data": [
      
   ]
} but on page have some posts which are shared by page

Comment: Graph Explorer returns an empty arrayas well https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=107621857718%2Fposts& Are you sure the posts were posted as the Page itself? Or by an administrator?

Comment: can you please tell me what should I do for my code :  OpenFB.get('/107621857718/feed')   ??

Comment: I got the unix time as per required but I am not getting all the results though i didn't given limit? => " /v2.3/107621857718/posts?since=1259020800'"